# How do I select a hyperlink as text in a browser?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, html, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Select Hyperlink Text in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/173200/how-to-select-hyperlink-text-in-google-chrome)

Every now and then you just want to copy some text that is a hyperlink. For example, the author is John O'Reilly and there's a hyperlink behind it that links to the author's page. But all I want is to select the words "John O'Reilly". Sometimes this is tricky to do. Is there some sort of keystroke that can disable the hyperlinks temporarily? For example, if you hold shift+ctrl+alt then you can click on a hyperlink and not get redirected so you can choose the text?

I am using Windows 7 and Chrome

Comment: What browser and OS you use would have been helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Chrome, you can right click on the link, select `Inspect element`, and double click on the text between the `<a> </a>` tags, followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. It's not ideal, but can be less fiddly than selecting the text with the mouse.

Answer (score 8):

Personally, I just drag the cursor over the text I want and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, It works 99% of the time, however, I would be interested to see if anyone else comes up with a better solution!

Edit -

On the odd occasion when you can't drag around an exact hyperlink for some reason (e.g. weird CSS causing problems) I try and copy more than is needed then paste into notepad and then copy the exact bit I need.

In the worst case scenario, I do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in order to copy the entire page... some fancy graphical sites really have problems selecting bits of text - but I have not done this in some time.

Comment: I have found some smaller fonts to be tricky when trying to copy the link text and not the link, but if you just move to the beginning edge of the hyperlink and then **slowly** move left a bit more, you can see the mouse cursor change and then start to highlight.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Firefox, you can use the Copy Plain Text add-on (most recent version available [here](http://uploading.com/files/a7355941/copyplaintext-0.3.5.xpi/)). This will allow you to select text and copy the basic text as it is via a right-click.

If you're like me and can't be bothered to hit Ctrl+C each time, you can also install the [AutoCopy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/383/) add-on. After installing Copy Plain Text, you'll need to check off the box in AutoCopy's options to enable the plain text feature.

Comment: In Firefox (which is not the case here), Firebug with its HTML tab and "Click an element in the page to inspect" feature is also very helpful to copy stuff (without having to display the whole page source and to search for the stuff you need). This is useful especially when you can't click at the page if you don't want it to display a popup or change something, or when selection is purely disabled through JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I copy it into the run dialog, which converts rich text to plain text.

Then I copy from the run dialog to the application.

If you'd like, I can write a quick program to convert the contents of the clipboard to plain text, so it works for all applications?