# Windows 7 (home) - How to select text in hypertext links

Tags: windows-7, browser, hyperlink

I have seen many duplicate questions like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/173200/how-to-select-hyperlink-text-in-google-chrome), [this](https://superuser.com/questions/184510/how-do-i-select-a-hyperlink-as-text-in-a-browser) and on the [Windows 7 Forums](http://www.sevenforums.com/browsers-mail/156468-how-select-text-links.html), but none of them have a satisfactory and perfect solution. Here's my problem:

I was reading [this article](http://techcrunch.com/2011/07/19/national-security-theater/); in the article there is a link mentioned like below:

> ["no leniency in monitoring social media sites."](http://www1.m.timesofindia.com/PDATOI/articleshow/9212357.cms)

I want to select  the word `leniency` from the link and copy it somewhere, but I have to select all the link text and then remove anything I don't need, or open the web site and then copy it from the destination once loaded. I guess there's a better way to do this.

Once, a friend of mine suggested some sort of <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F9</kbd> combination along with another key to do this, but I forgot that combination.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: What is your browser?

Comment: @wizlog..i think this is `windows ` hiddne property not  a browser specific..anyways i mostly read in chrome or firefox

Answer (score 1):

This is a browser specific issue since link rendering on screen is defined by the application, except when the application uses windows specific resources. An example of this is the fact that you can (or at least could until recently) do exactly what you are asking under Opera.

For other browsers there's only workarounds.

### For Chrome

Use the [ToggleLink Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pihmbjnaeenimjokcejnenhppigofjdi):

> Have you ever tried to select some text from a link? How cumbersome
>   and annoying it is? Very much !!!
>
> What you would normally do is carefully put the cursor at the
>   beginning or end of link, click and slowly drag until the wanted text.
>   Then you would paste the copied text somewhere and delete words you
>   don't want to. What a crap! isn't it?
>
> Now, with this chrome extension, it's easy and snappy.

I'm terribly sorry, but I don't know of an equivalent Firefox plugin.